# android splitting a string at every nth occurence and dealing with the remainder

Tags: java, android, string

i am trying to split a string in android at every nth comma, make a new substring out of it and then pass it to `android tts` engine so i am doing it in a for loop by keeping track of each comma and when i have hit the `nth` one,

do something! like this

```
if (list.size()>=columns) {   //list is a string array list
   for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) { //words is list.toString()
       if (words.charAt(i) == ',') {
           count++;
           scrollPos++;

           if (count == columns) {
               //columns is a dimen integer for this device its 4
               String ab = words.substring(startPoint, i + 1);  
               speakWords(ab);
               startPoint = i + 1;
               count = 0;
           }
       }
}
```

this works just fine except if count is say `14` i will get 3 strings of 4 items, and it disregards the remainder of 2 but i want the remainder to make its own string, i tried making a new `Int` called **leftOver** and giving it the value of startingpoint - words.length like this

```
Integer leftOver = startPoint - words.length();
```

and then creating the new string from leftover starting from the startpoint to the end of the list like this

```
if (leftOver > 3) { //its only 3 due to formatting would be 0 if i trimmed it and removed commas) 
    String ab2 = words.substring(startPoint, words.length());
    speakWords(ab);
}
```

but this just gets called twice first time with say 7 items and then the for loop runs again and startPoint is updated to 4 items less (columns value) leaving 3

so my question is either how do i get the remainder % or is there a better way maybe using string.split?

this is the entire block of code im using

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < SpeakRecyclerGrid.recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    list.add(((EditText) SpeakRecyclerGrid.recyclerView.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString());
}

Integer numOfWords = list.size();
words = list.toString();
Integer count = 0;
Integer startPoint = 0;
Integer scrollPos = 1;
Integer leftOver = 0;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

if (list.size() <= columns) {
    if (words.contains(", 's")) {
        formatString = words.replaceFirst(", 's", "'s");
        speakWords(formatString);
        System.out.println("formatString < 7"+formatString);
    } else if (words.contains(", ing")) {
        formatString = words.replaceFirst(", ing", "ing");
        speakWords(formatString);
        System.out.println("formatString < 7"+formatString);
    } else {
        speakWords(words);
        System.out.println("words < 7"+words);
    }
}

if (list.size()>=columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
        if (words.charAt(i) == ',') {
            count++;

            if (count == columns) {
               String ab = words.substring(startPoint, i + 1);
               scrollPos++;
               if (ab.contains(", 's")) {
                   formatString = ab.replaceFirst(", 's", "'s");
                   speakWords(formatString);
                   System.out.println("ab with s" + formatString);
               } else if (ab.contains(", ing")) {
                   formatString = ab.replaceFirst(", ing", "ing");
                   speakWords(formatString);
                   System.out.println("ab with ing" + formatString);
               } else {
                   speakWords(ab);
                   System.out.println("ab" + ab);
               }

               SpeakGrid.recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(columns * scrollPos);
               startPoint = i + 1;
               count = 0;
               leftOver = words.length() - startPoint;
               System.out.println("scroll" + scrollPos + "startpoint" + startPoint +"leftover" + leftOver);

               if (leftOver > 3) {
                   String ab2 = words.substring(startPoint, words.length());

                   if (ab2.contains(", 's")) {
                       formatString = ab2.replaceFirst(", 's", "'s");
                       speakWords(formatString);
                       System.out.println("ab2 with s" + formatString);
                   } else if (ab2.contains(", ing")) {
                       formatString = ab2.replaceFirst(", ing", "ing");
                       speakWords(formatString);
                       System.out.println("ab2 with ing" + formatString);
                   } else {
                       speakWords(ab2);
                       System.out.println("ab2" + ab2);
                   }

                   System.out.println("scroll" + scrollPos + "startpoint" + startPoint +"leftover" + leftOver);
                   count = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire string split operation,instead of pieces of it?

Comment: @CodeCody no worries ive added it to the question

Comment: A question I have is, why include the remainder operation inside the for loop? Shouldn't it be outside? We only know what the remainder is when the entire String is searched.

Comment: @CodeCody thank you must have been half asleep all working now